# Strange delegates and Actions behavior in .NET

Tags: c#, lambda, delegates

When I assign dog.Action as in the example:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public Action<object> Action { get; set; }

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Dog dog = new Dog();
        Dog dog2 = new Dog();
        dog.Action = x => Action(dog2);
    }
}

public class Dog
{
    public int width = 5;
    public Action<object> Action;
}
```

As you see in this example Action = null because it is not assigned.
dog.Action after assignment is Method = Void Button_Click(System.Object)
Can someone explain to me this behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can simplify your question to:

```
public class C
{
    public void M()
    {
        int x = 3;
        Action action = () => Console.WriteLine(x);
        // 'action' now points to method called something like "<M>b__0"
    }
}
```

If we put this code into the wonderful [sharplab](https://sharplab.io/#v2:CYLg1APgAgDABFAjAbgLACgoGYECY4DCcA3hnOQjlACxwCyAFAJQlkXsCWAdgC5wAecALxwsadO3ZJ8AQ2FxmwgHwJEATgb8m49gF8MuoA==), we can see what the compiler generated:

```
public class C
{
    [CompilerGenerated]
    private sealed class <>c__DisplayClass0_0
    {
        public int x;

        internal void <M>b__0()
        {
            Console.WriteLine(x);
        }
    }

    public void M()
    {
        <>c__DisplayClass0_0 <>c__DisplayClass0_ = new <>c__DisplayClass0_0();
        <>c__DisplayClass0_.x = 3;
        Action action = <>c__DisplayClass0_.<M>b__0;
    }
}
```

Because `action` captures the variable `x`, the compiler has had to create a whole new class called `<>c__DisplayClass0_0`, which has the field `x` on it. This class has a method called `<M>b__0()`, which uses the value of the field `x` in the call to `Console.WriteLine`.

In the method `M()`, the field `<>c__DisplayClass0_0.x` is used instead of the local variable `x`.

The delegate `action` points to the method `<M>b__0()` on this instance of `<>c__DisplayClass0_0`.